# Regarding Struts2 Spring AOP Logger

Tags: spring, struts2, spring-aop

In Strtus2 Action class I am having methods with name like getData(), getDetails(). Along with these I am having several getter/setters in my action class. 
I want to use Spring's AOP functionality for logging purpose. I need to maintain Log for getData() and getDetails() method which in turn are calling the service class but I don't want to maintain Log for the getter/setters which are present in the action class.
I don't want to hard code method name in my Aspect. Don't have any clue of how to implement this. Please help me out.

My AOP Logger class is like :

```
@Before("myPointCut() && allService()")
public void logEntryService(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("Start of " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() of "+joinPoint.getThis());
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}


@After("myPointCut() && allService()")
public void logExitService(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
    System.out.println("End of " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName() + "() of "+joinPoint.getThis());
    start = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

@Pointcut("@annotation(com.ing.trialbal.log.LogThis)")
public void myPointCut() {
    System.out.println("*************My PointCut");
}

@Pointcut("execution(* com.ing.trialbal.*.*.*(..))")
public void allService() {
    System.out.println("************All service");
}
```

LogThis.java

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface LogThis {

}
```

But this has created very tight coupling in my application as I always have to write @Logthis on every method in service and dao for having their logs.

Answer (score 1):

Pointcut bound with `@annotation()`. 
Something like

Annotation class

```
@Target({ ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Loggable {}
```

AOP Logger

```
@Pointcut("@annotation(com.Loggable)") //  && execution( ... )
```

Action class

```
@Loggable
Object getData() {}

@Loggable
Object getDetails() {}
```

Comment: Thanks..it is working fine. But this code has created tight coupling as for every method in service and dao layer I have to use @LogThis. I don't think this is the recommended solution for my problem.  Is there any thing like to avoid logging for all those get methods which are having corresponding member variable in the class.

Comment: How you organize the package of java classes (dao, service, action class) ?

Comment: yes exactly. Following are the packages : com.trialbal.action,
com.trialbal.dao,
com.trialbal.dbConnection,
com.trialbal.helper,
com.trialbal.log,
com.trialbal.resources,
com.trialbal.service,
com.trialbal.util,
com.trialbal.vo